# How to code 2 columns for bullet list in Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I want to list 3 points for 1 column and 3 points for second column. I want the "P" to be centered.

```
<div class="maindiv">
<p>This is a list of Adobe softwares</p>
<ul>
<li>Dreamweaver</li>
<li>Photoshop</li>
<li>Flash</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Indesign</li>
<li>Illustrator</li>
<li>After Effects</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: sorry didnt get your question..if you can, please show some graphical representation..

Comment: you can add `style="text-align:center;"` to the `<p>` to make it centered..

Comment: I want to attach a picture but i don't have enough points

Comment: add the image in pastebin and share the link with us..

Comment: What does it mean if I see the text centred in the Design view but when I preview it in browser, it is not centred?

Comment: lwell, actually that shouldnt happen...you try to share the image..well,i'll just try to reproduce it in a fiddle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/1pkbpxcp/)

Below given is the **HTML** that i've used

```
<div class="maindiv">
    <p class="centertext">This is a list of Adobe softwares</p>
    <div class="floated">
        <ul>
            <li>Dreamweaver</li>
            <li>Photoshop</li>
            <li>Flash</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="floated">
        <ul>
            <li>Indesign</li>
            <li>Illustrator</li>
            <li>After Effects</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the **CSS** that I've used

```
.floated {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
.centertext {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I want the bullet points to be against the div, floated. the bullets are indenting.

Comment: I meant, there is space on the left side of the bullets.

Comment: If I have more questions, i'll let you know. thanks!